# An activity contain both map and tab in android

Tags: android

Actually my map layout code with out tab is below one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayoutPeople" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
            android:id="@+id/mapView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:apiKey="@string/apikey" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />

<RelativeLayout     
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/linerlayouttransparent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.fitzengineering.teslaworldnet.presentationlayer.TransparentPanel
android:id="@+id/transparent_panel" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5px"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:paddingBottom="10px"
android:paddingRight="5px" >

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="5dip"
 /> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="People" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
 android:textSize="20dip"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="5dip"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal" android:clickable="false">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:width="30dp"/> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/TextViewName"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Name" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:width="100sp"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"/> 

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/TextViewLatitude" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="Address" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:width="100dip"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="150sp" 
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutPeople" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_margin="10dip">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:width="10dip"/>
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ImageViewBackinPeople" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:focusable="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/back_normal_icon"> 
    </ImageView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:width="30dip"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageViewAddRemoveinPeople" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:focusable="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/addremove_normal_icon"> 
    </ImageView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextViewEmpty" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:width="40dip"/>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ImageViewShowDetailsinPeoples" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/showdetails_normal_icon" 
    > 
    </ImageView>
     </LinearLayout> 
  </LinearLayout>
  </com.fitzengineering.teslaworldnet.presentationlayer.TransparentPanel>
  </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

in that when i add tab code at top of this code like

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</TabHost >
```

it shows error.
and other thing in java file i perform some operations on map when the java is extend with TabActivity those are not working.
so,Give me some suggestions for this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

extend your class with Tabactivity. setContent with Mapview. simple.

**Edit:**

well.

this is the sample code for activity looks.

```
public class BS_Main extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setContent(R.id.mapview).setIndicator("mapview_name",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_icon)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setContent(R.id.anotherview).setIndicator("tab2_name",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.anotherview_icon)));
  }
}
```

the layout of tab activity looks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"            
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <mapview tag here with ur map Api key>
        <anotherview tag>

    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

thats it.refer this [link](http://vkroz.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/programming-android-%E2%80%93-map-view-within-tab-view/) too.

Comment: Thanks. shall you give the example code of an application containing both or refer a website which having example related with this topic ?

Comment: I am not certain that this will work, as `MapView` requires `MapActivity`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity was deprecated in API level 13.try ActionBar with tabs navigation mode,in each tab you can use fragments include MapFragment.see the TabActivity documents http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html